# T table with infinity degrees of freedom

Tags: statistics, soft-question, statistical-inference

why is z table the same as a t table with infinity degrees of freedom. For example as df for the T distribution goes to infinity it becomes z ( standard normal) distribution. Is this true and why is this so? 
Thanks

Comment: if you're happy with probability density functions and taking limits, you could look at the definition of the pdf for the t distribution and take the limit as df$\to\infty$. Otherwise are you looking for an intuitive answer?

Comment: Is there an intuitive answer?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an explanation. The $t$-distribution $T$ is equal to:

$$ \frac{Z}{\sqrt{\chi^2 (k)/k}} $$

where $Z$ is the standard normal distribution. It can be shown, from the law of large numbers, that as $k$ approaches infinity, $\chi^2(k)/k$ approaches 1. And there you have it.

Comment: Thanks, to show it approaches 1 by l'hopital rule then?

Comment: Just use the Law of Large Numbers and use the fact that the expected value of each chi square random variable is 1.